# What is the difference between md5sum and sha1sum

Tags: command-line, files

I use the following two commands to get the checksum of text file, but it gives me two different checksums, why?

```
md5sum log
sha1sum log
```

Answer (score 7):

`md5sum` and `sha1sum` implement two different hashing algorithms, MD5 and SHA-1 respectively, so the outputs will be different.

Note that, `md5sum` generates 128 bit hash whereas `sha1sum` generates 160 bit hash.

As a side note, both of them are considered cryptographically insecure now. Consider using SHA-2 family of hashes e.g. `sha512sum` for any implementation that requires much robustness. Although just for checking the integrity of file(s), they can be considered *usable*.

Also check `man md5sum`, and `man sha1sum`.

[Video explaining checksums](https://youtu.be/OPVYUtfawEU).

Comment: Yes, I check the manual page of both the commands. Author of both commands is same, so what is a difference between these two algorithm?

Comment: @SagarParkale Here: http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/18612

Comment: So which one should I use md5 or sha1

Comment: @SagarParkale For simple file integrity checking, any one of them would do.

Comment: in above link,  says that md5 is broken, what does it means?

Comment: @SagarParkale See http://askubuntu.com/q/834814/216503

Comment: @Mina please don't go about editing all posts about checksums to spam some video, and certainly not as the first line of the post in headers. This is the third such post you have edited, by my count.

Comment: okay I didn't mean to exaggerate. sorry about that. @muru